Removing V-list
I am a South African citizen by birth and I am having a problem with my passport as it has been v-listed. When I enquired at Department of Home Affairs (DHA), I was told my name is there because there was a Zimbabwean who was deported in 2016 with the same surname and initials as me.
They said there is nothing they can do as the DHA system does not allow for the process to be reversed.

Do you have another citizenship? Have you submitted a formal appeal to have the prohibition removed? There are some contacts in this article that might be of use

Do you have a South African passport? If not, why don’t you ask for one? If you have one, how is a visa ban list relevant, as you don’t need a visa? You can’t be refused entry into South Africa…
